# return promise shows error in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that uploads images from an array to cloudinary.But when array is empty how can I return function without execute $http call.My code below

```
uploadPicture: function (files,title) {

            if (!files)
                promise = function(){}
                return promise;

            angular.forEach(files, function (file) {
                if (file && !file.$error) {

                    promise = $upload.upload({
                            url: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + cloudinary.config().cloud_name + "/upload",
                            data: {
                                upload_preset: cloudinary.config().upload_preset,
                                tags: 'myphotoalbum',
                                context: 'photo=' + title,
                                file: file
                            }
                        }).progress(function (e) {})
                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            return data;
                        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            return data;
                        });
                }
            });

            return promise;
        }

    }
```

If files is null then it shows error

```
delregservice.uploadPicture(...).then is not a function
```

In my controoler

```
$scope.Fn_SaveDeliveryAgent = function(){
                delregservice.uploadPicture($scope.filelist[0],$scope.title).then(function(d){
                $scope.delAgent.profile_pic = d;
             }).then(function(){

             delregservice.uploadPicture($scope.filelist[1],$scope.title).then(function(d){
             $scope.delAgent.license_pic = d;
             }).then(function(){

                delregservice.saveDeliveryAgent($scope.delAgent).then(function(d){
                     console.log(d);
             });
             });


            });
            }
```

How can I solve this problem? Please help.Thanks in advance and merry X mas

Comment: i do that, days ago and i envolved the updload under a new promise. The upload isnt a promise. Could be this

Answer (score 0):

If the files are empty you are returning an empty function, they wont have a then function.

an simple aproach is to wait for all promises (with [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)) and return them:

```
uploadPicture: function (files,title) {

        //if (!files)
        //    promise = function(){}
        //    return promise;
        var promises = [];
        angular.forEach(files, function (file) {
            if (file && !file.$error) {

                promises.push($upload.upload({
                        url: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + cloudinary.config().cloud_name + "/upload",
                        data: {
                            upload_preset: cloudinary.config().upload_preset,
                            tags: 'myphotoalbum',
                            context: 'photo=' + title,
                            file: file
                        }
                    })
                    // You wont need that here it will be passed with $q.all
                    //.progress(function (e) {})
                    //.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    //    return data;
                    //}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    //    return data;
                    //}));
            }
        });

        return $q.all(promises);
    }

}
```

this ensures that you will return every time a valid promise